# Charging Li-ion batteries at a constant current for a fixed time

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, safety, lithium-ion

I just saw an [Ebay Listing](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4Pcs-18650-4000mAh-3-7V-Li-ion-BRC-Rechargeable-Battery-Black-UK-Charger/231896290002?_trksid=p2047675.c100009.m1982&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D37255%26meid%3D0d0189007f5c4fe18dd1dcb120f512ac%26pid%3D100009%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D10%26sd%3D272255441279) for some cheap Li-Ion batteries and a charger that claims to be "safe" yet doesn't seem to have any overcharging protection as such - the charger is supposed to provide a "constant current" for a fixed amount of time. Am I wrong to assume that these batteries would perform better as fireworks than charge storing cells?

Comment: Well charging for a fixed amount of time implies that the charger has figured out the state of the batteries. It obviously hasn't so ...

Comment: I'd be wary of any Li-Ion battery product with exclamation marks in the description, it's entirely possible that it does have *some* kind of overvoltage protection, but would you risk it? At only 5 pounds, it'll make for a cheap fireworks display if it fails anyway...

Comment: I believe that among those who study lion batteries (vapers and flashlight(aka torch) afficianados) there is a consensus that you should not buy batteries from any company with "fire" in the name. The fact that these are supposedly 4 Ah is reason enough to not buy them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UltraFire sells flashlights, and the batteries and chargers to go with them; this is either one of their sets [or an impersonator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko25nYDAJvg). As the warning "Forbids to invert" and the fact that there is nothing physically preventing inversion show, we are dealing with a mixture of translation problems and uncertain design. I found other listings with the charger - [this one on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004LHFU62) is helpful.

The charger model is "UF-18650x2-charger", no datasheet found. They sell different batteries with the same charger, but this description is telling, and fits with the charger's DC output of 4.2 V, 650 mA:

> Ultrafire Li-Ion Rechargeable 18650 with IC Protection [...]
>
> Over charge and discharge protection. **Protection kicks in** : 2.75v and 4.2v.
>
> Over-Charging / Draining at 4.2v / 2,75v

[Another listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2x-18650-3-7v-5800mAH-Rechargeable-Li-ion-Battery-for-Flashlight-Smart-Charger-/331891108543?hash=item4d46406abf:g:gzcAAOSwRjNXNsTs) supports this:

> The charger provide output shortage protection when battery is fully charged

The closest I can get from UltraFire is this product page for a [better-looking charger](http://www.ultrafire-shop.net/UltraFire_Shop.php?view=productPage&product=30) (probably the original that this one cheaply imitates), which does mention "auto cut off". [A review](http://lygte-info.dk/review/Review%20Charger%20UltraFire%20WF-139%20UK.html) of the fancier charger says:

> The charger does not follow the recommended charge procedure for LiIon batteries, but it does charge to 4.2 volt and then turns off.

We can conclude the same for this rougher model based on just the listings.

So, not a high-end product, possibly a cheap imitation, but unlikely to start a fire. The original listing probably meant something like "the current is stabilized to produce a consistent charging time", not that the charger will force 650 mA for several hours while ignoring the battery voltage.

Comment: UltraFire puts their logo on all their products. Looking at the product image on the eBay page, UltraFire's logo isn't present on the batteries nor the charger dock. So I'm doubtful this product is made or vetted by UltraFire. Just sayin...

Comment: I didn't say they made it, just that it is their "set" - the same charger turns up with their flashlights and batteries in many places, and claims a serial number starting with UF. However, you raise a point I did not consider - there are apparently [fake versions of UltraFire products](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko25nYDAJvg). It is easier to ape a battery wrapping than a charger casing, so perhaps the whole set is imitation.

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure your fire insurance premiums are paid up and your family members know and have practiced a fire evacuation plan.

But seriously, if a product sounds too good to be true based upon its claims or price, it likely isn't true. If a product isn't certified by an independent, third-party product testing lab—e.g., Underwriter's Labs (UL) here in the U.S., it would be prudent to think twice before spending £5 for an item that could start a battery fire and burn down a £250,000 home along with all your belongings, pets, and vehicles, or start an an apartment complex fire (hope your renter's insurance has at least £5 million in liability coverage), etc. If this product fails you have ALMOST NO GROUNDS FOR LEGAL RECOURSE. About the best you can hope for is to have eBay refund you the £5 plus what ever shipping costs there are.

FWIW, note that the "Item Location" shown on the eBay page says "Shanghai, China", but further down on the same webpage there's a statement that says the product ships from "Hong Kong" (INCONSISTENCY == BIG RED FLAG), there's no way for you to verify it isn't a low-quality knock-off product, and you likely cannot sue the seller in Shanghai or the supplier in Hong Kong to remedy any losses you incur as a consequence of purchasing or using this product.

Note that if you buy stuff locally you can actually return it for a refund if it doesn't work. Furthermore, the product liability laws where you live are actionable. If you buy locally and the product fails and causes damages, your legal recourse could realistically include a product liability lawsuit against the retailer, the distributor(s), the manufacturer(s), the company that designed the product, etc. in an attempt to (a) stop further distribution and sale of a defective or hazardous product, and (b) receive compensation for any damages the product caused.

One final (off topic) comment. It's not recommended to include hyperlinks to eBay product pages when posting questions/answers/comments on StackExchanage or on other forum websites, because eBay hyperlinks eventually "go dark" resulting a broken link in your text and the unavoidable loss of pertinent information.